# Parsing a PayPal REST Credit Card Transaction Response (JSON)

Tags: c#, json, rest, paypal

I am using the latest release of PayPal's REST API for PayPal and Credit Card transactions via C# ASP.NET 4.5 framework website. The transactions are working perfectly in the sandbox and the response is displaying all the data associated with the transaction.

What I want to do is display that information in a more user friendly way using labels. How do I parse the JSON response into labels or textboxes?

This is the current code that displays unfriendly response.

```
try
            {
                APIContext apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();
                Payment createdPayment = pymnt.Create(apiContext);
                CurrContext.Items.Add("ResponseJson", JObject.Parse(createdPayment.ConvertToJson()).ToString(Formatting.Indented));
            }

            catch (PayPal.Exception.PayPalException ex)
            {
                if (ex.InnerException is PayPal.Exception.ConnectionException)
                {
                    Label4.Text = (((PayPal.Exception.ConnectionException)ex.InnerException).Response);
                }

                else
                {
                    Label4.Text = (ex.Message);
                }

                CurrContext.Items.Add("Error", ex.Message);
            }
            CurrContext.Items.Add("RequestJson", JObject.Parse(pymnt.ConvertToJson()).ToString(Formatting.Indented));
```

Comment: Is it still working today? If so can you help me out with the json body request for card payments?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this tonight actually and it was a bit of work.  Here is how to at least get a structured object back to utilize and write your own translation class/method.

```
public class PaypalApiError
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string message { get; set; }
  public List<Dictionary<string, string>> details { get; set; }
  public string debug_id { get; set; }
  public string information_link { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can get a usable object back by modifying your code slightly.

```
catch (PayPal.Exception.PayPalException ex)
{
    string error = "";
    if (ex.InnerException is PayPal.Exception.ConnectionException)
    {
        var paypalError = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaypalApiError>(((PayPal.Exception.ConnectionException)ex.InnerException).Response);
        // method below would parse name/details and return a error message
        error = ParsePaypalError(paypalError);
    }
    else
    {
        error = ex.Message;
    }

    return new PaymentDataResult(){ 
            Success = false,
            Message = error
        };
}
```

You would have to create the ParsePaypalError() method to return the errors based on what matters to you.  I don't see an easy way to parse it and just display useful messages out of the gate when it will be the most common status'VALIDATION_ERROR'.  Here is a link to the error status/messages.

[PayPal Rest API Errors](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#errors)

Comment: Sorry so late returning to this post. Are you saying that I have to parse out the return error codes in order to populate labels or textboxes with the payment information?

Comment: If you want to get detailed error message, yes.  However, I went back to using the Classic SDK for doing a credit card payment.  It was a lot easier than implementing the REST stuff in WebForms. Unfortunately, I wasted over a day on the REST stuff.  Classic SDK is here and has good examples: https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-dotnet

Comment: I am just trying to get the transaction details like the token etc. Getting the error codes is not a problem. I used to use Classic but now with the implementation of the new PayPal Advance solution, you must use REST. So my question still stands, how to get the trans details?

Comment: In your example, createdPayment.id would have the transaction id.  createdPayment.state would have created/approved/failed/canceled/expired.  These are automatically populated after the pymnt.Create() call (provided an exception isn't thrown).