# Rest C# capture error response in Payment.Create()

Tags: paypal

I'm following the Rest sample (PaymentWithCreditCard) and I can't figure out how to get the actual Error code.

```
Payment pymnt = new Payment();
pymnt.intent = "sale";
pymnt.payer = payr;
pymnt.transactions = transactions;

try
{
    APIContext apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();
    Payment createdPayment = pymnt.Create(apiContext);
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    // how can I get the Error code??
}
```

How can tie the general Exception to the list of Error codes (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/)?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545679/parsing-a-paypal-rest-credit-card-transaction-response-json

Comment: The link you provided is for the Classic API error codes. The REST API error information can be found on the [PayPal REST API Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#errors) site.  If you're using the most recent version of the .NET REST SDK, then you'll want to catch the exception as a `PayPal.Exception.PaymentsException` or `PayPal.Exception.HttpException`. Both of those exception classes should provide quick access to the error details returned from PayPal.